# What does PYTHON_INSTALL_LAYOUT do in AWS?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services

I'm using Amazon's Elastic Map Reduce and the variable `PYTHON_INSTALL_LAYOUT` is set. It's not clear to me what this does, but there are a variety of blogs which indicate that things like `pip` are broken if the variable is left existant.

What does this variable do?